# Changing the pre selected value of a dropdown to value before it

Tags: cypress

[image]

In cypress i am trying to get the above day dropdown to - 1 day from the current pre populated day (so in example i would need to get the 16th selected) not sure how to get cypress to select the current value minus one

[image]

just thinking logically if it would need to grab the current day -1 and then re select the correct date but not sure how to get cypress to do this in a simple way. Fairly new to cypress (maybe obvious)TIA

cy.get('#ctl00_Main_EndDay').invoke('value').as('Day') cy.get('#ctl00_Main_EndDay').type('@Day'-1)

Comment: Please add HTML and the Cypress code you've attempted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by replacing `.as()` with `.then()`.

Alias `.as()` is not for this situation.

Also change

- value is probably (maybe always) a string since it comes from the web page. Add `parseInt()` conversion to make it a number, then you can subtract 1 from it.
- your picture shows `<select> + <option>` elements, so maybe `.select()` command is better than `.type()` command

```js
cy.get('#ctl00_Main_EndDay')
  .invoke('val')
  .then(dayString => {
    const day = parseInt(dayString)
    cy.get('#ctl00_Main_EndDay')
      .select(day-1)
  })
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and advice, i will try this out and update.

Comment: code worked great but modified slightly to call 'val' instead of 'value'

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I'll fix it in the answer.